# How to use a decorator with a coroutine in Python?

Tags: python, python-decorators, coroutine

I'm trying to make a program that spawns two processes which commnicate one another. I have read about coroutines and thought it would be good to adopt it  this time, and since a coroutine needs to be primed before being used, I thought it would be good to make a decorator to automatically do that.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from functools import wraps

output, input = mp.Pipe()



def co_deco(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        cr.send(None)
        return cr
    return wrapper

class sender(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe = pipe

    def run(self):
        print('RECEIVER PID: ', os.getpid() )
        while True:
            self.pipe.send( random.randint(0,10) )
            time.sleep(1)

class receiver(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, pipe):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.pipe = pipe

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.coroutine.send( self.pipe.recv() )

    @co_deco
    def coroutine(self):
        while True:
            msg = yield
            print( datetime.now(), msg )



if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()

    sen = sender(pipe=input)
    rec = receiver(pipe = output)

    sen.start()
    rec.start()
```

`sen` process sends a random integer to `rec` process every second. Whenever an integer arrives, `coroutine` method(of `rec`) binds it to `msg` and prints it out with the current time.

I see no problems with the code, but it shows an error message:

```
self.coroutine.send( self.pipe.recv() )
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I assume there's a problem with decorating the coroutine, but I have no idea what the problem exactly is and how to fix it. I'd like to get some help with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to call the coroutine:

```
def run(self):
    # Create and initialize the coroutine
    cr = self.coroutine()

    while True:
        # Send the data
        cr.send( self.pipe.recv() )
```

---

If you wish for it to be class-bound, this is the way

```
def co_deco(func):
    cr = func()
    cr.send(None)
    return cr


@co_deco
def coroutine():
    while True:
        msg = yield
        print( datetime.now(), msg )
```

---

And for instance-bound, this is the way.

```
def co_deco(func):
    @property
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            # Get the coroutine from the instance object under a 
            # name with a leading underscore
            return getattr(self, "_" + func.__name__)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        cr = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Set the coroutine from the instance object under a 
        # name with a leading underscore
        setattr(self, "_" + func.__name__, cr)
        cr.send(None)
        return cr
    return wrapper


@co_deco
def coroutine(self):
    while True:
        msg = yield
        print( datetime.now(), msg )
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for your answer! I thought ```cr = func(*args, **kwargs)``` in the decorator would do the job already. Is it not possible to just use it as ```self.coroutine.send()``` without calling it before the loop, maybe using a decorator?

Comment: Remember, `cr = func(*args, **kwargs)` is called only when you call the function. I gave you 2 examples consisting of a different `cr` for class and for instance

Comment: @maynull You're welcome! If there anything more you wish to ask, you're welcome to post at the comments or as a new question on stackoverflow. I highly suggest reading about generators for future programming. Have a good day too :-)